# Is there a way to get a forensic image of EC2 instance

Tags: linux, forensics, aws

I currently have an instance on AWS which was compromised and resulted in me losing control. I have shutdown the instance since then, but require a forensic image of the volume so that I can analyze it further.

I have mounted the volume onto another instance to run `dd` command. when I check the size of the volume it shows 16MB used. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you check the size of the volume?

Comment: Df -h after mount.

Comment: Are you sure you mounted the correct partition?

Comment: Yes, it was /dev/xvdf1.

Comment: What does `fdisk` say about the entire disk?

Comment: If you want help, you need to post the exact commands you ran. Don't just say “I check the size of the volume”, copy-paste the **complete** command. If you see 16MB used when you expected more, it's probably because you passed the wrong argument, but we can't help you if you don't say what argument you passed.